# How can I generate a certificate for a Linux app?

Tags: c#, websocket, https, certificate

I am building my first Client-Server application, with a Secure WebSockets server written in C# and running on Ubuntu.

I am using a client for connecting to the server and exchanging data. The thing is, if I access *https://localhost:5000/index.html*, my browser assures me the connection is secured.
However, if I try to access *https://127.0.0.1:5000/index.html*, the browser alerts me that the certificate can't be trusted, and so, warns be this connection is not secure.

My final goal is to access the server from inside my LAN (let's say by accessing *https://192.169.0.10:5000/index.html*, with 192.168.0.10 being the server's address), and I honestly don't know how to generate a valid certificate.

And even if I manage to generate one, what should I do with it in order to secure my communication? Please help me as this matter is starting to eat a lot of time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a self signed SSL snakeoil certificate with just an IP address however this will still show a warning in chrome when a client tries to access your website via HTTPS as you are not a credible authority. However despite the warning in chrome network traffic will still be encrypted via HTTPS.

Alternatively Let's Encrypt Certbot issues SSL certificates from a credible authority known as R3 (Let's Encrypt) so chrome will not show a warning message when a client tries to access your website via HTTPS. You need a domain name if you want R3 (Let's Encrypt) to issue you an SSL certificate.